# A couple questions

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

We are a non profit with very specific needs

1. Does Civi do deposits by batch?
2. Can Civi track attendance? 
   When our clients come in they have redeemable points and credits that they get monthly and use throughout the month. Is there a way of tracking these balances? On the first of each month these quotas reset. Is that a possibility. Currently we are using Google Sheets for this.
3. Can we set permissions for viewable information?
4. Where is Civi information stored?

Comment: I guess you should read these link - https://civicrm.org/blog/cividesk/how-many-organizations-use-civicrm-where-how         and    https://civicrm.org/blog/bdaniels/6-ways-to-use-civicrm-part-1  --- I guess this helps !!!

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I would recommend taking a look at the user guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

just a guess based on your name: Belgian or Dutch? If so, come to CiviCamp Brussels to learn more about CiviCRM: https://civicrm.org/civicamp/brussels-2018

You ask a few questions that are not simply answered in one sentence and this would be a good way to find answers and discuss your needs with other CiviCRM users and partners.

Short and quick answers:

1. not sure what you mean there. I guess an answer could be: yes, CiviCRM allows sending of financial transactions in batch but I am not sure if that is what you want to do.
2. CiviCRM can track all sorts of things, you would have to explain to me what you mean exactly. But I think you would certainly be able to use custom fields for this.
3. Yes, depending on your CMS and the CiviCRM entities you are using.
4. In the MySQL database on the server that you either host yourself or your hosting service provider delivers you.

Answer (score 1):

These screenshots are a bit dated, but here's [documentation of the deposits by batch functionality](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-entry-of-contributions/#1-create-a-new-batch-for-data-entry).